# JSR 303 - javax.validation - Validate a date

Tags: java, validation, date

I have a Java EE application and I want to validate a Date.
With a String I do this:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
...
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
private String myString;
```

But now I have two dates which I want to validate. The user can in the frontend system write a String in a text field which will be transferred via JSON (I have to use text field, I can not use a datepicker).

So my backend does have this in my domain class:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yy")
@Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date myStartDate;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yy")
@Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date myEndDate;
```

I want to validate against the format "dd.MM.yyyy". How can this be done?

And, I do not think so, but is there an automatic validation to check if the start date is before the end date? I only found `@Future` and `@Past`.

So the only solution is to use a @Pattern, a regular expression?!

Thank you in advance for your help, Best Regards.

Comment: Couple of things: the `@DateTimeFormat` is not part of JSR-303 and `mm` stands for minutes, not months. Also how does changing `"dd.MM.yy"` to `"dd.MM.yyyy"` fail? Since you seem to be using Spring MVC (which this annotation is part of), you might want to revise/retag your question. At least, JSR 303 doesn't offer [any](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html) annotations for this.

Comment: Yes, I can change to `dd.MM.yyyy`, but there is no validation.

Comment: I also fail to understand how pattern validation is useful on a `Date` instead of a `String` since the `Date` doesn't store any information about its internal format. Anyway, I don't do Spring, but I think you just need to implement a [Validator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/validation.html). That's at least how I would do it if it were JSF.

Comment: Validating date format in JSON representation is a responsibility of your JSON parser/mapper. You need to reformulate you question and describe technology that you use to parse JSON.

Comment: I use the Validator of Spring. And this is based on JSR 303. The problem is, that I want to validate automatically and return an error message. This works fine with i.e. `@Size`. And then I think I can do a `@Pattern`. I used this one `@Pattern(regexp="\t(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d\t")` but an error occurs with an invalid escape sequence?!

Comment: First, `@Pattern` only works on `String` (as stated in its javadoc). Second, backslashes are escape characters in `String`. You need to escape it with another one to represent an actual one.

Comment: Okay, so I have to do it in another way...

Comment: It sounds like you need to either 1) insert an intermediate object with a string to validate or 2) configure your JSON library to only accept that format for deserialization into a Date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@DateTimeFormat is used during web data binding, when mapping request parameters onto an object (assuming you have enabled it with `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` or manually.)  It's not generally going to be used when deserializing JSON into an object.  How are you reading in your JSON?  What are you using to deserialize it?  You can't validate a java Date object after the fact for the formatting, you have to check up front before deserialization.

There are no multi-field constraints built in.  You'll want to write your own type level constraint if you want to compare two properties on an object.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to validate it with `@Pattern(regexp="\t(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d\t")`, but there is an error that it is an invalid escape sequence. Yes, I can check it before sending to the backend system, but I have no access to the frontend system, I am only the "backend master" and I have to check if the date format is okay, so the Pattern will be enough in the first step.

Comment: you must double all you \\ in a java regex, since \ is already the escape character for java strings, before it goes to the regex engine.